# Reset form input field after clicking submit on react js using useState

Tags: reactjs

I have a sign in form working just fine and I want to set the input fields blank after clicking submit. I searched for similar questions, but most people were using react hook and other stuff that I am not using, so I don't know how to adapt these solutions to mine. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
    FormWrap,
    Container, 
    Icon, 
    FormContent, 
    Form,
    FormH1,
    FormLabel, 
    FormInput,
    Text, 
    FormButton, 
    TextLeft,
    Heading,
    Subtitle,
    TextWrapper,
    LogoPage,
    ModalWrapper,
    FormMiniLabel, Wrapper, FormInputTerms, TermLink, FormMiniLabelWarning} 
from './SignInElements'
import Axios from 'axios'
import { Modal} from '../Modal/Modal';




const SignIn = ({}) => {
    const[name, setname] = useState("");
    const[cpf, setcpf] = useState("");
    const[tel, settel] = useState("");
    const[email, setemail] = useState("");
    const[terms, setterms] = useState("");

    const register = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register/',  {
            name: name,
            cpf: cpf,
            tel: tel,
            email: email,
        }).then((response) => {console.log(response)});
        console.log(name);
        console.log(cpf);
        console.log(tel);
        console.log(email);
        console.log(terms);
        
    };
    
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const OpenModal = () => {
        setShowModal(prev => !prev);
    };


    function AllFunc() {
        register();
        OpenModal();
    }


    function SubmitButton(){
        if (name && cpf && tel && email && terms){
          return <FormButton type="submit" onClick={AllFunc}>Cadastrar</FormButton>
        } else {

          return (
          <FormButton type="submit">Cadastrar</FormButton>)
        };
      };

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <FormWrap>
                    <FormContent>
                        <TextLeft  action="#">
                            <Icon to="/"> <LogoPage src={require('../../images/Brand.svg').default} /> </Icon>
                            <TextWrapper>
                                <Heading>Bora parcelar com a Wowpen? </Heading>
                                <Subtitle>Cadastre-se completando o formulário e participe do nosso grupo seleto de beta testers. Tenha acesso antecipado a funcionalidade de parcelamento e interaja diretamente com o nosso time de desenvolvimento.</Subtitle>
                            </TextWrapper>
                        </TextLeft>
                        <Form action="#">
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Como podemos te chamar?</FormLabel>
                            <FormInput placeholder="Nome Sobrenome" type="text" required onChange={(e) => setname(e.target.value) }/>
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Compartilha seu CPF?</FormLabel>
                            <FormMiniLabel>É importante para verificar sua identidade.</FormMiniLabel>
                            <FormInput placeholder="000.000.000-00" type="text" required  onChange={(e) => setcpf(e.target.value) }/>
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Qual seu número de Whatsapp?</FormLabel>
                            <FormMiniLabel>Esse é nosso principal meio de comuniação.</FormMiniLabel>
                            <FormInput placeholder="(DDD) 90000-0000" type="text" required onChange={(e) => settel(e.target.value) } />
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">E seu e-mail?</FormLabel>
                            <FormMiniLabel>Prometemos não enviar spam ;)</FormMiniLabel>
                            <FormInput placeholder="exemplo@email.com" type="email" required onChange={(e) => setemail(e.target.value) } />
                            <Wrapper>
                            <FormInputTerms type="checkbox" required onChange={(e) => setterms(e.target.value) } />
                            <FormMiniLabel>Li e concordo com os <TermLink>Termos e a Política de Privacidade</TermLink> da Wowpen. </FormMiniLabel>
                            </Wrapper>
                            <SubmitButton/>
                        </Form>
                        <Modal setShowModal={setShowModal} showModal={showModal}/>
                    </FormContent>
                </FormWrap>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default SignIn
```

Basically, there is the SubmitButton function that, when all fields are filled, triggers the functions that send the data for a MySQL database (register) and open a modal (openModal). I have tried to add a function called reset like:

```
function reset () {
   setname("");
   settel("");
}
```

To be called on the submit button click, but it's not working to make the fields blank.

The Form component is below (i am using styled-components):

```
export const Form = styled.form`
    background: #fff;
    background-image: url(${img});
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: col2;
    padding: 80px 147px;
    align-content: center;

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        padding: 32px 32px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        padding: 80px 60px;
        height: 1200px;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        background-size: cover;
        
    }
    

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width: 1501px) {
        height: 1200px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        justify-content: center;
    }
`;
```

And the Form Input component (also with styled-components):

```
export const FormInput = styled.input`
    padding: 16px 16px;
    /*margin-bottom:  32px;*/
    border: none;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
`;
```

Does anyone know how can I set the input fields blank after submitting?

Comment: Show us the Form and FormInput component

Comment: Just updated the question with them. I am using styled-components and the Form is a styled.form and the FormInput a styled.input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed all inputs to a controlled input, so whenever your state changes it automatically reflect in your input box also
Added value to all FromInputs
`<FormInput value={name} ...`

SO after changing to controlled elements you can now clear text box value by clearing the state

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
    FormWrap,
    Container, 
    Icon, 
    FormContent, 
    Form,
    FormH1,
    FormLabel, 
    FormInput,
    Text, 
    FormButton, 
    TextLeft,
    Heading,
    Subtitle,
    TextWrapper,
    LogoPage,
    ModalWrapper,
    FormMiniLabel, Wrapper, FormInputTerms, TermLink, FormMiniLabelWarning} 
from './SignInElements'
import Axios from 'axios'
import { Modal} from '../Modal/Modal';




const SignIn = ({}) => {
    const[name, setname] = useState("");
    const[cpf, setcpf] = useState("");
    const[tel, settel] = useState("");
    const[email, setemail] = useState("");
    const[terms, setterms] = useState("");

    const register = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register/',  {
            name: name,
            cpf: cpf,
            tel: tel,
            email: email,
        }).then((response) => {
           console.log(response)
            setname("");
            settel("");
            setcpf("");
            setemail("");
            setterms(false)
        });
        
    };
    
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const OpenModal = () => {
        setShowModal(prev => !prev);
    };


    function AllFunc() {
        register();
        OpenModal();
    }


    function SubmitButton(){
        if (name && cpf && tel && email && terms){
          return <FormButton type="submit" onClick={AllFunc}>Cadastrar</FormButton>
        } else {

          return (
          <FormButton type="submit">Cadastrar</FormButton>)
        };
      };

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <FormWrap>
                    <FormContent>
                        <TextLeft  action="#">
                            <Icon to="/"> <LogoPage src={require('../../images/Brand.svg').default} /> </Icon>
                            <TextWrapper>
                                <Heading>Bora parcelar com a Wowpen? </Heading>
                                <Subtitle>Cadastre-se completando o formulário e participe do nosso grupo seleto de beta testers. Tenha acesso antecipado a funcionalidade de parcelamento e interaja diretamente com o nosso time de desenvolvimento.</Subtitle>
                            </TextWrapper>
                        </TextLeft>
                        <Form action="#">
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Como podemos te chamar?</FormLabel>
                            <FormInput value={name} placeholder="Nome Sobrenome" type="text" required onChange={(e) => setname(e.target.value) }/>
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Compartilha seu CPF?</FormLabel>
                            <FormMiniLabel>É importante para verificar sua identidade.</FormMiniLabel>
                            <FormInput value={cpf} placeholder="000.000.000-00" type="text" required  onChange={(e) => setcpf(e.target.value) }/>
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Qual seu número de Whatsapp?</FormLabel>
                            <FormMiniLabel>Esse é nosso principal meio de comuniação.</FormMiniLabel>
                            <FormInput value={tel} placeholder="(DDD) 90000-0000" type="text" required onChange={(e) => settel(e.target.value) } />
                            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">E seu e-mail?</FormLabel>
                            <FormMiniLabel>Prometemos não enviar spam ;)</FormMiniLabel>
                            <FormInput value={email} placeholder="exemplo@email.com" type="email" required onChange={(e) => setemail(e.target.value) } />
                            <Wrapper>
                            <FormInputTerms checked={terms} type="checkbox" required onChange={(e) => setterms(e.target.checked) } />
                            <FormMiniLabel>Li e concordo com os <TermLink>Termos e a Política de Privacidade</TermLink> da Wowpen. </FormMiniLabel>
                            </Wrapper>
                            <SubmitButton/>
                        </Form>
                        <Modal setShowModal={setShowModal} showModal={showModal}/>
                    </FormContent>
                </FormWrap>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default SignIn
```

Other than this method I suggest to use a single state object to handle all the values,
like `const [data, setData] = useState({})` by using this method you can handle all value in one object and you could quickly clear it

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I just tried to implement your code, but the fields are not going blank :/ I tried to add a console.log("test") in the part where you added the setname("") and the other ones after the Axios post response. When I click the button to submit, there is nothing on the console. I don't know why the console.log is not being executed. I have checked and the data is being saved on the database. I will try to create a single state object!

Comment: have you added the `value` to  all inputs like `<FormInput value={name} ...` this ?  also note that setname("")  is a asynchronous operation it will not instantly update the state, it will only update the value on its next render, by the above method, input box will clear its value, on its next render after successful API response

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you :) I did add the value to all inputs and I don't know if my post has any issue with the response, but I just moved the setname("") and the other outside the then(), like this:
`}).then((response) => {console.log(response); }); setname("");
settel("");
setcpf("");
setemail("");
setterms(false);`
Now all the fields go blank just fine! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `onSubmit` to the `Form` tag

```
 <Form action="#" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

then create a function that should perform after clicking the Submit button

```
const onSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault()

   // do something
   
   setname("");
   settel("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just tried to apply it, but the field setname and settel don't go blank. I even replaced the setname and settel by a console.log("test") to see if the function was being executed, but nothing is showing on the console when I click the submit button. The weird thing is that the button is inside the Form tag, so it should work. Could this be because the button element is being returned from a function? Do you have any idea of what can be causing this? I can send a screenshot if it helps :)

Comment: @windside13 try onSubmit to betray the button `<FormButton type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Cadastrar</FormButton>`

Comment: @windside13 to understand why onSubmit does not work for a form, you need to look at its component

Comment: Tried using `<FormButton type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Cadastrar</FormButton>` with the onSubmit with a console.log("test") and when I clicked the button it printed the message on the console! Then, I added the setname(""), clicked the submit button, "test" was printed on the console, but the name input did not get blank :/